# Exception in thread "main" chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Cannot reassign to read-only AluAccu.?: OpResult[UInt<2>]

Tags: chisel

I want use chisel to achieve addr in alu.
The verilog code like this

```
assign {Carry,Result} = A + t_no_Cin + Cin;
```

So I wirte the chisel code like this

```
Cat(io.carry, result_temp) := (io.din1 + t_no_cin + op_ctrl1)
```

But an error was returned

I want to ask the whether the splicing operation in Chisel can only appear on the right side of the equal sign. Because I found the example of the splicing operation in Chisel is just like this format

```
val temp := Cat(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right that Cat must be used like

```
val word = Cat(highByte , lowByte)
```

So I fail to see how Verilog expressions like

```
assign {c_out, sum} = a + b + c_in;
```

can be constructed in Chisel, as you suggest.